# Javascript Adding line break before "-" and after "."

Tags: javascript, text

I have a field in a postgres database like this:

> BACHILLER - Ciencias y Tecnología. - Humanidades y Ciencias Sociales. - Idiomas: inglés y francés. PROYECTOS Y SERVICIOS PEDAGÓGICOS - Aula abierta de apoyo (PROA). - Departamento de Orientación con dos orientadoras: atención individualizada y colectiva de alumnado y familias. - Tutoría coordinada por niveles. - Plan de Normalización Lingüística del Euskera. - AULATICE. INNOVACIÓN Y PROYECTOS DE FORMACIÓN - Página web del centro, dinámica y de apoyo a la enseñanza. - Blogs: Orientación, Psicología, AGENDA 21 ESCOLAR (A21e), Matemáticas, Física, PARADISE, Números, Asociación de Padres y Madres… - AGENDA 21 ESCOLAR (A21e). Participación en la agenda municipal. Certificado de Escuela Sostenible. - Proyecto plurilingüe: ENGLISH PROJECT. - Proyecto del Aula de Aprendizaje de Tareas (AAT): cocina. - Participación activa en los proyectos convocados por el Dpto. de Educación. SERVICIOS - Transporte escolar subvencionado en ESO. - Comedor escolar (ESO). - Acceso a Internet para el alumnado (WI-FI) e Intranet. INSTALACIONES - Enfermería. - Dos bibliotecas informatizadas (ESO y Bachiller). - TV y DVD en aulas. - Cuatro aulas de Informática. - Salón de actos. - Laboratorios de: Física, Química, Ciencias Naturales y Fotografía. - Talleres de: Plástica, Tecnología y Electrotecnia. - Aulas especializadas de: música, arte, euskera, castellano, inglés, AULATICE… - Amplias instalaciones deportivas, cubiertas y al aire libre. Frontón.

I want to use javascript to convert this text into:

```
BACHILLER
- Ciencias y Tecnología.
- Humanidades y Ciencias Sociales.
- Idiomas: inglés y francés.
PROYECTOS Y SERVICIOS PEDAGÓGICOS
- Aula abierta de apoyo (PROA).
- Departamento de Orientación con dos orientadoras: atención individualizada y colectiva de
alumnado y familias.
- Tutoría coordinada por niveles.
- Plan de Normalización Lingüística del Euskera.
- AULATICE.
INNOVACIÓN Y PROYECTOS DE FORMACIÓN
- Página web del centro, dinámica y de apoyo a la enseñanza.
- Blogs: Orientación, Psicología, AGENDA 21 ESCOLAR (A21e), Matemáticas, Física, PARADISE,
Números, Asociación de Padres y Madres…
- AGENDA 21 ESCOLAR (A21e). Participación en la agenda municipal. Certificado de Escuela
Sostenible.
- Proyecto plurilingüe: ENGLISH PROJECT.
- Proyecto del Aula de Aprendizaje de Tareas (AAT): cocina.
- Participación activa en los proyectos convocados por el Dpto. de Educación.
SERVICIOS
- Transporte escolar subvencionado en ESO.
- Comedor escolar (ESO).
- Acceso a Internet para el alumnado (WI-FI) e Intranet.
INSTALACIONES
- Enfermería.
- Dos bibliotecas informatizadas (ESO y Bachiller).
- TV y DVD en aulas.
- Cuatro aulas de Informática.
- Salón de actos.
- Laboratorios de: Física, Química, Ciencias Naturales y Fotografía.
- Talleres de: Plástica, Tecnología y Electrotecnia.
- Aulas especializadas de: música, arte, euskera, castellano, inglés, AULATICE…
- Amplias instalaciones deportivas, cubiertas y al aire libre. Frontón.
```

I need to code a little function that makes the trick. I think that inserting a new line break in the oupput text before every "-" and after a "." sign would be enough. It has to be smart enough not to add two line breaks when both requirement are met.

My javascript knowledge is quite limited and i need same help this time...

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would probably be using regular expressions.
If you want to learn more about regular expressions, I suggest checking out [RegexOne.com](http://regexone.com/).

My solution would be:

```
textblock.replace(/ - /g, "\n- ").replace(/\./g, ".\n").replace(/^\s*\n/gm, "");
```

First I replace every "-" and every "." with a line break, and afterwords i remove any empty lines that occur when both conditions are met.

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rv0bpwr0/)

Comment: This works better than mine, using the multiline modifier `m` with the global modifier `g`.

Answer (score 1):

```
input.replace(/[-]/g, "\r\n-").replace(/((\.\s*)([A-Z]{2,}))/g,".\r\n$3")
```